# Understanding JavaScript custom event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've been doing quite a bit of research (Google) on custom events, but I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

My question is as follows: in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/WMnsc/3/), I have `div`s inside of a `div` I'm sliding and wanted to make a custom event that is attached to all of the child `div`s so whenever a child `div`'s offset left reaches a certain range the custom listener on that `div` will execute.

So really the question is: I'm I able to make truly custom event listeners on the same level as `onchange`, `click`, `onmouseup` etc. Which will listen for what I want them to listen for?

Comment: "Custom event" means that you *manually* fire an event - you can't just specify a condition to fire an event when met.

Comment: yeah I ment to say custom event listeners

Comment: Yes, you just register listeners for custom events. Only they will be useless if the event is not triggered…

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using jQuery.  It's very easy to define custom events with jQuery.  I use a pattern like this:

```
// Constructor
function Colorbar() {
    this.events = $({});
    // (Whatever else is in the class)
}
colorbar = new Colorbar();
```

You can then listen for an event of any name:

```
colorbar.events.on("currentcolorchanged", function(e, cb, ncolor) {
    helper.doColorChanged(ncolor);
});
```

And trigger it:

```
this.events.triggerHandler("currentcolorchanged", [this, ncolor]);
```

If you are working with DOM objects, just cache the jQuery of the DOM object:

```
var $ele = $("#myElement");
$ele.on("myCustomEvent", function(e) {
    // Event handler
});
$ele.triggerHandler("myCustomEvent");
```

Comment: your example seems like I'll have to manually trigger the event. what i'm trying to build is an event listener that automatically fires a function when the object i've attached it to meets the conditions i've specified. like when onmousemove fires when the mouse moves over object it's attached to.

Comment: @zero You will have to manually trigger the event regardless, even with my solution.

Comment: @zero, all events manually trigger.  Mouse events trigger because the browser manually triggers them for you, when the mouse does something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make truly custom events that work like onchange click onmouseup etc, however you have to write the listener code yourself based on existing events or methods.

In this case, you'll want to check the offset value in the move event, and when it reaches that target value, trigger the custom event.

Comment: well if you're talking about the onmove event, that only works in IE which would be perfect for this.

Comment: I'm talking about your existing move function, `function move(e){` which is working just fine in chrome.

Comment: how would i go about creating a custom listener? as every search i've done as only returned custom events that are manually triggered.

Comment: Inside of your move function, add a check that tests the offset value for your condition, and if met, trigger the custom event.

Comment: well the reason for a custom listener is that this has to update automatically as you're sliding, so from that i can gather what div is being displayed/year you are on

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WMnsc/5/ When the truesliderx is between a certain range, worky is logged to the console.

Comment: actually i'm trying to get the offset of the divs with the class "boxes" to tell which one is currently in view (lined up with the far left side of the red div)